# Custom primary category in appstore connect

Tags: xcode, react-native, app-store-connect

How can i add a custom a primary category in App store connect for my react-native app.
I am trying to assign my app a category that is not present in the list.

Please let me know what are they ways to do it.

Comment: The categories are AppStore categories. It configured where in the AppStore your app will appear. You can’t create custom ones. If you want to improve SEO stuff you need to look at the keywords etc…

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add Custom Categories in App Store Connect as per this documentation https://developer.apple.com/app-store/categories/. However the only thing you can do is you can use better ASO keywords. Please go thorough this article https://developer.apple.com/app-store/search/